# What is the fastest way to transfer an MS SQL database backup from one Windows server to another?

Tags: windows, database, data-transfer

Would the best approach be to copy it onto a hard disk or is there a faster way?

Comment: The answer depends on how large the DB is and if they are networked (and how fast). Sending a 10MB database to a server in another town our another country is probably the fastest using the net. Cloning a multi-gigabyte DB to a server sitting next to it is the other extreme.. So to answer it we need more information.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, if the machines are networked then your best bet is to dump the DB onto a shared storage and restore it back to the other server.

If they're not networked, then dump it and 7zip it onto a DVD-R and restore it to the new server.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Zip the file, and use the command `copy /z` which allows you to recover if the connection is dropped.  You can also try Windows Robocopy.

A final option is to copy the file to any attached external storage, and physically move it. That will surely be the fastest method.